# What's The Degree Of Given ODE?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

What is the degree (order looks 2) of the following ODE (and whats the way to find it?) ?
$$k{(y'')}^2 = (1+ {(y'')}^2)^3 $$

Answer (score 1):

The order is 2. Just looks at the largest power of the highest derivative. In this case the right hand side of your equation will involve something with $(y'')^6$. Hence the degree is 6 and the order is indeed 2.

Comment: This Textbook http://books.google.co.in/books?id=yKVi7lMDMpcC, says that degree is two. (In Section 8.4)

Comment: Yeah that was also my first thought. I think that the definition of order and degree are often mixed up and maybe use differently in different places.